# Is there an easier way to format arrays when declaring and populating them?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm wondering if there is some sort of auto formatter online or some other way to takes lists of data online which are plain text, AKA a list of names: "Patricia, George, Albert, Eugene, Jack, Bob, Alex", and get them according to the format you need when declaring a list in c#, where each element has to be within quotation marks for strings, and separated by commas such as `{"Patricia", "George", "Albert", "Eugene", "Jack", "Bob", "Alex"}` do you don't have to do the strenuous task of adding in all those commas and quotation marks, especially when you have a large data set.

Comment: I'd use vim macro recording -- are you familiar with vim?

Comment: you can easily create one in python or bash or something similar. Or use an online regex utility.

Comment: Replace `, ` with `"," ` using your text editor of choice?

Answer (score 1):

You can format it easily in almost every text editor, replacing all commas followed by a space ( `,`  ) with comma within quotation marks ( `", "` ). Then adding quotation marks at the beginning and at the end.

Alternatively, you can do it directly in c#:

```cs
names =  "Patricia, George, Albert, Eugene, Jack, Bob, Alex"
string[] namesArray = names.Split(", ")
```